# Как тестировать авторизацию и последующие методы с помощью JUnit

Tags: java, junit

У меня есть простая авторизация в приложении, протестировал его, он работает. Решил дальше протестировать методы, для которых нужна авторизация, интересен момент ListHouse у меня проходит тест, а ContractHouse выводит исключение, что авторизация не была произведена. [Фулл](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent) код. Также подключил аннотацию для класса UserDetailsService:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AuthController.class)
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
```

Логи:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Код:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HouseTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private ContractRepository contractRepository;
    @Autowired
    private HouseService houseService;
    @Autowired
    private ContractService contractService;
    @Autowired
    private HouseRestController houseRestController;
    @Autowired
    private HouseRepository houseRepository;

    @MockBean
    private AuthController authController;

    @MockBean
    private ContractDto contractDto;

    @BeforeEach
    public void AuthLogin() throws Exception {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setEmail("igor@mail.ru");
        userDto.setPassword("igor");
        authController.getLoginPage(userDto);
    }

    @Test
    void ContractHouse() {
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 31);
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 20);
        ContractDto contractDto = new ContractDto();
        contractDto.setEndDate(endDate);
        contractDto.setStartDate(startDate);
        contractDto.setHouseId((long) 5);
        contractDto.setTenantId((long) 5);
        String freeHouse = houseRestController.findAllByDate(contractDto);
        assertThat(freeHouse).isNotNull();
        assertThat(freeHouse).isEqualTo("Квартира занята");
    }

    @Test
    void ListHouse() {
        List<House> freeHouse = houseService.findfreehouse();
        assertThat(freeHouse).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Comment: Может это поможет

`@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;


    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .build();
    }`

Comment: Или попробовать добавить анотацию с указанием класса, где конфигурирете авторизацию
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Ваш класс с авторизацией})`
 Данная анотация ставится над тестовым классом

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий я над классом, где провожу тесты пишу эту строку: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = AuthController)` А он мне её подчёркивает и говорит Attribute value must be constant

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий первый вариант попробовал. Не помогло. Правильно ли я ошибку смотрю, у меня появляется TestResult и ещё ответвления, нажимаю на ContractHouse - это тот метод, который я тестирую и смотрю ошибку. Если верно, то у меня всё та же ошибка. Если нужно смотреть TestResult , то java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods. Смотрел по этой ошибке решения - они оказались в том, что нужно junit оставить на 4 или 5 сделать.

Comment: Вот так должно быть, только класс не контроллера должен быть `@ContextConfiguration(classes = AuthController.class)` а конфигурации, где вы используете `UserDetailsService`

А смена версии junit, я так понимаю не помогла?

Comment: 1. Как можно сменить версию Junit? 2. Сделал аннотацию 
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = AuthController.class)` в классе `public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {` 3. Ошибка по прежнему та же

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113817/discussion-between-blacit-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В spring-security есть [поддержка тестов](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test). В твоём случае тебе надо использовать [@WithMockUser](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#test-method-withmockuser).

Было

```java
    @Test
    void ContractHouse() {
    //...
    }
```

Должно стать

```java
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = {"user:write"})
    void ContractHouse() {
    //...
    }
```

Эта аннотация лежит в библиотеке

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

P.S. удали `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, он уже встроен в `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: Верно понимаю, что над классом для тестов должно быть так, как сейчас и больше в целом ничего не нужно? `@SpringBootTest
public class HouseTest {` Мне ваш ответ помог, спасибо

Comment: Да, верно. В этом случае больше ничего не надо.